# Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable s.t. $f'(x) \neq 1 \ \forall x$. Then $f$ has at most one fixed point.

Tags: proof-verification, derivatives

> Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function s.t. $f'(x)
> > \neq 1 \ \forall x \in [a,b]$. Prove that $f(c)=c$  has at most one
>   solution $c \in [a,b]$.

My attempt:

Let $f'(x) \neq 1 \ \forall x \in [a,b]$  but suppose $\exists \ c_1, c_2 \in [a,b], c_1 \neq c_2$ s.t. $f(c_1) = c_1$ and $f(c_2) = c_2$. Then by the Mean Value Theorem $\exists  \ d \in [c_1, c_2]$ s.t. 
$f'(d) = \frac{f(c_1) - f(c_2)}{c_1 - c_2}$
$= \frac{c_1 - c_2}{c_1 - c_2} = 1$ which is a contradiction since $f'(x) \neq 1 \ \forall x \in [a,b]$. Hence, there is at most one fixed point.

$\Box$

I was able to show that the number of fixed points cannot be greater than $1$. Do I need to show the possible existence of such a point if at all it exists? Or is this it?

Comment: It would be good to exhibit such a function that has one fixed point to show the bound is sharp.  However for the usual reading of the question, your proof is "good enough" (tm).

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is o.k.

Example: let $f(x):= e^x+x.$ Then $f$ has no fixed points. Furthermore we have $f'(x) \ne 1$ for all $x$.